# How to align Right to left order confirmation email in Opencart V 2.x

Tags: html, opencart2.x

I need to know how to set the order confirmation emails that are sent after placing orders and confirming orders and registration confirmation emails to be aligned Right to Left as I am using Arabic Language.
I am using Opencart Version 2.2.0 ?

This is the code I have :

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
$mail->setText($text);
$mail->send();


// Admin Alert Mail
if ($this->config->get('config_order_mail')) {
    $subject = sprintf($language->get('text_new_subject'), html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), $order_id);

    // HTML Mail
    $data['text_greeting'] = $language->get('text_new_received');

    if ($comment) {
        if ($order_info['comment']) {
            $data['comment'] = nl2br($comment) . '<br/><br/>' . $order_info['comment'];
        } else {
            $data['comment'] = nl2br($comment);
        }
    } else {
        if ($order_info['comment']) {
            $data['comment'] = $order_info['comment'];
        } else {
            $data['comment'] = '';
        }
    }

    $data['text_download'] = '';

    $data['text_footer'] = '';

    $data['text_link'] = '';
    $data['link'] = '';
    $data['download'] = '';
```

Thanks